# Code to remove .php worked initially but not on Godaddy shared hosting

Tags: php, .htaccess

I recently added the code below to my .htaccess file while testing my new site on a dedicated server I have. The code is intended to remove the .php extension on a PHP page.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

With this added, I was able to link internally from one page to another without a .php extension. For example, example.com/page1 linked to example.com/page2 without a .php extension for either page even though they were both php pages.

When I moved the site to a shared hosting account with Godaddy though, none of my internal links worked. The rep at Godaddy said the .php had to be included on all internal links and couldn't really explain why it had worked on my dedicated server and not their shared hosting.

Does anyone know why this might be and what I can do to fix the problem?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Make sure the .htaccess file migrated between servers properly and contains the content you expect.

Comment: Why does everyone jump straight to `mod_rewrite` for these things? Content negotiation via [`Options MultiViews`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options) is so much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking to much into it, this guy (http://davidwalsh.name/mod_rewrite-htaccess-godaddy) seems to have had similar problems and found that adding:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

to this .htaccess file solved his issue.

Comment: Awesome! Adding "Options -Multiviews" solved the problem. Amazing. Such a simple adjustment, but that's all I had to do. Thanks so much for your help with this. I really do appreciate it. Thank you thank you thank you!!!